# How to fix yacc warning attribute is untyped with fatal error unexpected end of file

Tags: c, yacc

I want to code the calculate of moy in Yacc so I do this code

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
// Fonction qui permet de claculer la moyenne
double moy(int*ls,int size )
{
int som=0;
 for(int j=0; j<size;j++)
      som+=ls[j];
  return (som/size);
}

/* La structure de la table*/
%}

%union {
  int value;
  struct s{int *ls; int size;} str;
}
%token nb
%type <value> E
%type <str> L
%left '+','-'
%left '*','/'
//%right '^'
//%right moins_unaire
%%
Ligne  :   E '\n'       {printf("%d \n",$1);}
;

E    :   E '-' T    {$$=$1-$3;}
     |   E '+' T    {$$=$1+$3;}
     |   T          {$$=$1;}
     ;
T    :   T '*' F
     |   T '/' F
     |   F
     ;
F    :   '(' E ')' {$$=$2;}
     |   nb  {$$=$1;}
     |   fct  {$$=$1;}
     ;
fct: nf '('L ')' {if ($1==1) {
         $$=  moy($3.ls,$3.size);
     }
     ;
nf   : 'moy' {$$=1;}
     ;
L    :   L ',' E {$$.ls=$1; $$.ls[$$.size++]=$3;}
     | E {$$.size=1; $$.ls=malloc(50); $$.ls[0]=$1;}
     ;
%%
main ()
{
    yyparse();
}
```

but once i compiled it i have gotten those warnings:

Compiling...
mo.y

```
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(35) : warning Y4003: '$3' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(36) : warning Y4003: '$3' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(37) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(43) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(44) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(44) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(45) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(45) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(47) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(48) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(51) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(53) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(53) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(53) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(53) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(54) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(54) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(54) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(54) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(62) : fatal error Y1015: unexpected end of file found in action

g - 1 error(s), 19 warning(s)
```

I noticed that once I delete this two lines:

```
%type <value> E
%type <str> L
```

Untyped error disappear. I searched a lot but i did not reach to fix the problem.

**What should I do ?**

Comment: This line looks problematic: `fct: nf '('L ')' {if ($1==1) {`. The braces aren't matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
%type <value> E T F
```

to fix the type errors.

As noted by @JeffMercado, the premature EOF is caused by the excess first brace on

```
fct: nf '('L ')' {if ($1==1) {
```

And

```
%left '+','-' 
%left '*','/'
```

This is not right. The commas should be spaces.

Comment: Doing that Now the number of warnings reduced to : Compiling...
mo.y
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(42) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(43) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(45) : warning Y4003: '$1' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(46) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped
C:\Users\LE\Desktop\exos\moy\mo.y(50) : warning Y4003: '$$' : attribute is untyped

Comment: If you seriously think that is legible I am sorry but you have rocks in your head. Edit it into your question. And tell us which are the line numbers involved. But in general, `$$: attribute is untyped` means exactly what it says, and the solution is to make sure that it *is* typed.

Comment: well to be honest i did not understand for my first experiance that the error mean that i have to type that mean that every token should be declared under token and for rules put them under type. So not understanding that lead me to every time think that is a new error.Whatever u think me so stupid but it was just a misunderstood from me and confusion that lead me to this error

Comment: anyway after working harder later i could do something like this

Comment: https://github.com/ZinaTaklit/CompileEvaluateAndInetermediateCodeForArithmetiqueOperation

Comment: so u are not a wiser teacher "EJP"  and u should not tell me that. but i have learned from my mistake and u can see what i have reached to do

Comment: Wise enough to give you the right answer, mate, and to try to raise your standards of legilibility. Shooting the messenger doens't accomplish anything.

Comment: i do agree with u